# What does "WINAPI" in main function mean?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, winmain

Could you please explain to me the `WINAPI` word in the `WinMain()` function?

In the simplest way..

```
#include <windows.h>

int -->WINAPI<-- WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Goodbye, cruel world!", "Note", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

Is it just some Windows funky mode?

What does it do?  Or rather what is this C++ feature I haven't encountered yet?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`WINAPI` is a macro that evaluates to [`__stdcall`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx), a Microsoft-specific keyword that specifies a calling convention where the callee cleans the stack. The function's caller and callee need to agree on a calling convention to avoid corrupting the stack.

Comment: so why is it in this specific place? couldn't they give the macro one line above?

Comment: The calling convention keyword goes between the return type and the function name because that's how someone working on a C compiler defined it many years ago. I don't know the reasoning behind the syntax, or even which compiler was the first to support specifying calling conventions (cdecl, pascal, fortran, etc.). Microsoft? Borland? Lattice? Something else?

Answer (score 10):

WINAPI is a macro that expands to [__stdcall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/stdcall) which means that the callee cleans the stack.

Answer (score 10):

This is a macro definition intended to denote the Windows calling convention.  From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687850.aspx):

> The way the name is decorated depends
>   on the language and how the compiler
>   is instructed to make the function
>   available, that is, the calling
>   convention. The standard inter-process
>   calling convention for Windows used by
>   DLLs is known as the WinAPI
>   convention. It is defined in Windows
>   header files as WINAPI, which is in
>   turn defined using the Win32
>   declarator __stdcall.

Answer (score 2):

It's Windows-specific. It specifies the calling convention. WinMain gets called by Windows, and this ensures that the caller and callee agree on the calling convention.