# Viewing Win32 messages

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Hello everyone I am new to windows32 programming and I have a couple of questions-:

When I use the following code in a program it works fine -:

```
while(GetMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0))
  {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);                                  
    DispatchMessage(&msg);  
}
```

But when I replace null of GetMessage to hwnd(the handle of the window just created) the doesn't seem to close it still remains running in the background. Why does this happen when I replace NULL with hwnd means I am receiving messages for only one window then why doesn't it work????

```
while(GetMessage(&msg,hwnd,0,0))
  {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);                                  
    DispatchMessage(&msg);  
}
```

By the way the windows function is-:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message,
                              WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam){

    switch(message){
                case WM_DESTROY:
                     PostQuitMessage(0);
                     break;
                default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wparam, lparam);
                }
    return 0;
}
```

Secondly-:

Is there any way I can see all the messages sent to any particular window????

Thirdly-:

What is the reason behind writing __stdcall(WINAPI) when compiling my windows programs ????

A quick reply would be appreciated.Thank You.

Comment: With regard to the second part of your question, [Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460726.aspx) can show you the messages being sent to particular windows.

Answer (score 3):

1. `GetMessage` returns `0` (making the loop end) only when it receives a `WM_QUIT`, but a `WM_QUIT` is not associated to any particular window, so it is never received if you have a `GetMessage` that asks only messages for a certain `hWnd`.
2. If it's a window of yours, you already see them inside their window procedure; if you want to filter them before dispatching them to their window procedure, you can check the `msg` structure that is populated by `GetMessage` before calling `DispatchMessage`.
3. The whole Windows API uses the `stdcall` calling convention (I think because it is slightly faster/produces less boilerplate code than the usual `cdecl`), so also your callbacks must follow that calling convention. Notice that you must use `WINAPI` (i.e. `stdcall`) only on functions that are called by Windows API functions, for the other ones you are free to use whatever calling convention you like best.

Comment: About 2), not all messages come from GetMessage: messages that are sent (synchronously) as part of other message processing goes to the window procedure as nested call, now by the loop.

And by the way, WM_QUIT is one of these, since it is normally an *answer* to something else, like a click on the close button, or a response to a "close" command and the like.

Comment: @Emilio: all correct, in facts, since he owns the window procedures, the correct way to see all the messages targeted to a window of his is to just check them inside the appropriate wndproc.

Comment: Is there any message that is sent once a windows is fully initialized when the entire display has been drawn to the screen ???

Comment: Define "fully initialized" - it's an application-dependent thing, how is windows supposed to know?

Comment: when all resources are loaded. my situation is that i want to show a dialog box right after the window has been created.

Comment: Check out `WM_INITDIALOG` (called when the dialog is displayed) or `WM_CREATE` (called when the window is created).

Answer (score 1):

`PostQuitMessage` generates `WM_QUIT` which is processed by the message queue, but not associated with a particular window. By filtering only `hwnd` messages in your call to `GetMessage`, you don't process `WM_QUIT`.

Regarding seeing all messages being sent to a window / thread / process, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038730/i-am-looking-for-a-windows-spy-application

Finally, regarding `__stdcall`, see [What does "WINAPI" in main function mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348442/winapi-main-function)

Comment: Is there any message that is sent once a windows is fully initialized when the entire display has been drawn to the screen ???

Comment: For what purpose? Not all windows are displayed. There is `WM_PAINT` or `WM_CREATE` - either might work for you.