# PIVOKE Stackimbalance error

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

Hello I was wondering what is wrong with this PINVOKE declaration?
I am not finding the mistake.

This is the Code in C++

```
BOOL HOOKDLL_API WINAPI SetHook(int HookType, BOOL bInstall,
                                    DWORD dwThreadId = 0,
                                    HWND hWndCaller = NULL);
```

This is my declaration:

```
[
        DllImport("CppHookDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
        //EntryPoint="?SetHook@@YGHHHKPAUHWND__@@@Z",
        EntryPoint = "SetKeyboardHook",
        ExactSpelling = true,CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)
    ]

    public static extern bool SetHook(int HookType, bool bInstall, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] UInt32 dwThreadId, IntPtr hWndCaller);
```

Thankt in advance.

Comment: Hmm. What C++ compiler? 64-bit issues? Is `int` there 32 bits? Is bool 1 byte?

Comment: C# `bool` is marshalled as a 4 byte Windows `BOOL`.

Comment: Are you sure the function uses the stdcall convention? I think cdecl is the default for functions declared as extern "C" (although it was a long time ago since I worked with this so I may very well be wrong)

Comment: @erikkallen `WINAPI` is a macro that expands to `__stdcall`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348442/what-does-winapi-in-main-function-mean

Comment: Wrong function, do keep the mangled name.  A "SetKeyboardHook" function would not have the *HookType* argument, it already knows the hook type :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are just importing the wrong function. The function in the unmanaged code is named `SetHook`, but you are importing a function named `SetKeyboardHook`. Presumably the function `SetKeyboardHook` has a different signature which would explain the stack imbalance warning.