# What does the CONFIGRET return-type mean?

Tags: c++, winapi, driver, typedef, return-type

I was taking a look at the [PnP Configuration Manager functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549794(v=vs.85).aspx) and saw that each begins with these three macros:

```
CMAPI CONFIGRET WINAPI
```

I had to dig inside *CfgMgr32.h* to find `CMAPI`, which is defined as:

```
#if !defined (_CFGMGR32_)
#define CMAPI     DECLSPEC_IMPORT
#else
#define CMAPI
#endif
```

According to [Tim Roberts' article on DLL's in Kernel Mode](http://timr.probo.com/wd3/071503/KernelDlls.htm), this allows functions with `CMAPI` to be either loaded at run-time or link-time. And we already know that `WINAPI` is just a [macro for a calling convention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2348447/975724).

But what about `CONFIGRET`?  From *CfgMgr32.h*, it is defined as:

```
//
// Standardized Return Value data type
//
typedef _Return_type_success_(return == 0) DWORD        RETURN_TYPE;
typedef RETURN_TYPE  CONFIGRET;
```

I've never seen this before, what does this mean?  What is the return type of these functions?

Comment: The return value is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh780226.aspx): *"If the operation succeeds, the function returns CR_SUCCESS. Otherwise, it returns one of the CR_-prefixed error codes defined in Cfgmgr32.h."* The particular type is not really interesting. It happens to be a `DWORD` annotated with [SAL Annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235402.aspx). This one simply says: *"0 means success"* (see [Annotating Function Behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159529.aspx)). SAL is used for static code analysis tools.

Comment: Neat, I never knew about SAL Annotations.  Why don't you wrap up your comment in an answer so I can accept it?  Thanks.

Comment: 'this article' link above is dead. please replace it with working link.

Comment: @Laxman Good catch, next time I'll try to post article titles to help people find via Google search. I've updated the question to include the most recent article. For historical reasons, you can also look at the article as of Oct 25th, 2015 on the wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20151025190943/http://www.wd-3.com/archive/kerneldlls.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying data type for `CONFIGRET` is a `DWORD`, as defined in *CfgMgr32.h*:

```
//
// Standardized Return Value data type
//
typedef _Return_type_success_(return == 0) DWORD        RETURN_TYPE;
typedef RETURN_TYPE  CONFIGRET;
```

`CONFIGRET` is an alias for `RETURN_TYPE`, and `RETURN_TYPE` an alias for a `DWORD` with additional semantic information attached by means of [SAL annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235402.aspx) (SAL annotations are used by static code analyzers).

[Annotating Function Behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159529.aspx) contains detailed information on this particular annotation:

> `_Return_type_success_(expr)`
>
> May be applied to a typedef. Indicates that all functions that return that type and do not explicitly have *_Success_* are annotated as if they had `_Success_(expr)`. *_Return_type_success_* cannot be used on a function or a function pointer typedef.

---

The `CMAPI` preprocessor symbol defined in *CfgMgr32.h* as

```
#if !defined (_CFGMGR32_)
#define CMAPI     DECLSPEC_IMPORT
#else
#define CMAPI
#endif
```

serves a different purpose, than what you proposed: It allows the same header file to be used for the consumer and producer of the library. The producer defines the `_CFGMGR32_` preprocessor symbol, and provides the function definitions. The consumer doesn't define the `_CFGMGR32_` preprocessor symbol, and `CMAPI` expands to an import specifier (`__declspec(dllimport)`, defined in *ntdef.h*). This is used for [Load-Time Dynamic Linking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684184.aspx) (vs. [Run-Time Dynamic Linking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685090.aspx)). It is not used for static linking at all.