# C function pointer crashes program?

Tags: c, function, pointers, winapi

Im trying to write a function that gets the address of MessageBoxA from a structure pointer that I pass to it and then uses that address to call MessageBoxA. The problem is that I try to call MessageBoxA 5 times with this method, but my program always crashes after 3 times and i have no idea why.

```
void code(struct ShellD * s)
{

    s->pMsgBox(NULL,"s","s",MB_OK);

    s->pMsgBox(NULL,"s","s",MB_OK);

    s->pMsgBox(NULL,"s","s",MB_OK);

    s->pMsgBox(NULL,"s","s",MB_OK);

    s->pMsgBox(NULL,"s","s",MB_OK);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

struct ShellD SD;

SD.pMsgBox = GetProcAddress(LoadLibraryA("user32.dll"),"MessageBoxA");

code(&SD);

}
```

Comment: What's your ShellD structure? In particular, what calling convention have you declared on the pMsgBox type?

Comment: pMsgBox is defined as  int (*pMsgBox)(HWND,LPCSTR,LPCSTR,UINT); i know that this is not the problem because the first 3 MessageBoxes appear without a problem. Edit: I have tried other functions too, but no matter what function i try to call it always crashes after 3 times

Comment: Like @Rup said, you need to use the correct calling convention on your function pointer.  The declaration of `pMsgBox` *is* the problem, it is causing a stack misalignment from each call that gets worse and worse the more you use it.

Comment: Try `int (WINAPI *pMsgBox)(HWND,LPCSTR,LPCSTR,UINT)`

Comment: that actually worked :) What difference does the WINAPI make?

Comment: @Sinnlosername See [What does “WINAPI” in main function mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348442/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> pMsgBox is defined as int (*pMsgBox)(HWND,LPCSTR,LPCSTR,UINT);

You've dropped the `WINAPI` from the declaration of `MessageBoxA`:

```cpp
int
WINAPI // <--
MessageBoxA(
    __in_opt HWND hWnd,
    __in_opt LPCSTR lpText,
    __in_opt LPCSTR lpCaption,
    __in UINT uType);
```

`pMsgBox` should be like this instead:

```
int (WINAPI *pMsgBox)(HWND,LPCSTR,LPCSTR,UINT)
```

What's the difference?

- The Windows API functions use the [stdcall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/stdcall?view=vs-2019) calling convention (also known as the Pascal calling convention). One of the characteristics of `stdcall` functions is that they clean up the stack space used by any arguments passed in.
- By contrast, in the default [cdecl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/cdecl?view=vs-2019) calling convention, the calling code cleans up the stack space for any arguments it passes in.

By using the wrong calling convention in your declaration of `pMsgBox`, both your `code()` function and the `MessageBoxA()` function are moving the stack pointer to remove passed arguments, and after a few times you've probably drifted the stack pointer out of the current stack frame and are then overwriting other things on the stack e.g. the return function pointer. This is probably what's causing the crash.